# Sum the negative numbers of an array using reduce() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, foreach, iterator

I'm trying to build a function that sums the negative numbers of a given array. I want to use the reduce() function here. This seems like a dead simple exercise. Using a ternary operator to check if number is negative and therefore to sum it to the total. However, result is not as I hoped:

```js
const reducer = (tot, num) => ((num < 0) ? tot + num : tot);
const sumOfNegative = numbers => numbers.reduce(reducer);

console.log(sumOfNegative([3, -1, 0]))
// => 2
```

Expected to get -1 here. Not sure I have a good grasp at what reduce() is doing each step. What am I doing wrong and how is the code iterating through the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't provide a second argument to `.reduce`, then it will take the first array value as the start of the accumulation (`tot`), meaning that the first element of your array will not be checked for being negative.

Solution: provide the second argument: make it 0. This also means you no longer need the ternary operator:

```
const sumOfNegative = numbers => numbers.reduce(reducer, 0);
```